# Enforcing RC4 cipher and testing enabled ciphers with OpenSSL

Tags: security, apache-http-server, ssl, openssl, httpd

I am trying to enable and enforce the RC4 cipher on Apache 2.4. I checked the [Apache SSL HOWTO](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html). It says the RC4 cipher can be enabled in the two ways below:

1. SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
   SSLHonorCipherOrder on
2. SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+EXP:+eNULL

Which one is the better way to enable and enforce the RC4 cipher? And how do I test the enabled ciphers with OpenSSL?

Comment: Just checking: You do know that RC4 is broken, so this is just so you can play around with how broken RC4 is, right? Because in 2015 you don't want to force RC4 unless you want leave your traffic insecure.

Comment: Actually the requirement was to enable RC4 to sustain BEAST attack, I am a beginer in security stuff so I didnt really know that RC4 is broken. Whats the other way or cipher suites to be enabled to sustain BEAST attacks?

Comment: If you want to be secure against BEAST, require TLS 1.2.

Comment: Please stop cross posting your questions across the network. When you have a question, post it on **one** Stack Exchange site.